# ffmpeg buffer queue drop overflow, dropping

Tags: ffmpeg

I got

```
buffer queue drop overflow, dropping
```

error when I try to run this code

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -i logo.png -loop 1 -report -filter_complex "overlay=20:15,subtitles ='sub.srt'" -c:a copy -q:v 1 -f segment -segment_time 600 "out_%d.ts"
```

but if I removed the overlay in complex filter it works find but Produce the video without logo

The following command is working but without the logo

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -i logo.png -loop 1 -report -filter_complex "subtitles ='sub.srt'" -c:a copy -q:v 1 -f segment -segment_time 600 "out_%d.ts"
```

Comment: Both your commands are encoding to mpeg2video with a high bitrate. Is that the codec you want? If you add `-c:v libx264`, it should be faster.

Comment: but I am still getting this error 
buffer queue drop overflow, dropping

Comment: But is the output produced?

Comment: no 
this the error 
[swscaler @ 0000000002931fc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 00000000029b3a00] [framesync @ 00000000027dd6e8] Buffer queue overflow, dropping.

Comment: Remove the `-loop 1`